# Odoo POS delay create customers

Tags: javascript, python, delay, odoo-8, point-of-sale

How can I manipulate the delay when a customer is created in the Odoo POS and when it's available in the backend?

Also the other way around, when creating a new customer in the backend.

Thanks,

Jesse

Comment: You can't manipulate it. Because it is just taking friction of seconds after creating customer from front to backend. It doesn't take that much of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, We're working on large sets of data, so sometimes it can take up to several minutes. I've written a workaround to check again on the customer when pushing the order